# Edge browser on windows 10 Enterprise LTSB?

Tags: windows-10

So I'm running on Windows 10 Enterprise LTSB, which doesn't automatically come with Edge.

Is it possible to install edge on this version of windows 10?

Thanks

Comment: ["LTSB will receive only security and hot fixes, and no new features, for ten years.](http://www.zdnet.com/article/some-windows-10-enterprise-users-wont-get-microsofts-edge-browser/) ... But the reason Microsoft won't provide Edge to Enterprise users on LTSB is because the company expects to roll out new features and feature updates to Edge on a regular basis"

Answer (score 1):

Basically converting MC10's comment into an answer:

From the [ZDNet article they linked](http://www.zdnet.com/article/some-windows-10-enterprise-users-wont-get-microsofts-edge-browser/):

> But the reason Microsoft won't provide Edge to Enterprise users on LTSB is because the company expects to roll out new features and feature updates to Edge on a regular basis, as both Gartner and Microsoft officials note. That means it would be kind of pointless to include the evolving Edge browser if it's not going to be updated.

This is further confirmed by recent Google Searches, where [responses from MS staff](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/windows/en-US/f801501d-fc18-4425-9a0d-e6fb603a0bc8/windows-10-ltsb-is-it-possible-to-add-edge-browser?forum=win10itprogeneral) are that the following will not be included in LTSB:

> Microsoft Edge, Windows Store client, Cortana (limited search capabilities remain available), Microsoft Mail, Calendar, OneNote, Weather, News, Sports, Money, Photos, Camera, Music, and Clock. Therefore, it’s important to remember that Microsoft has positioned the LTSB model primarily for specialized devices.

Answer (score 0):

It's not possible to install it for that Win10 channel, no.
LTSB does not have a compatible version of Edge.